# Java XpowYmodN function, DiffieHellman

Tags: java, function, math, diffie-hellman

I need for the Diffie Hellman protocol to create a function XpowYmodN. I have found online the following function:

```
    public long XpowYmodN(long x, long y, long N) {
    long result = 1;
    final long oneShift63 = ((long) 1) << 63;

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; y <<= 1, i++) {
        result = result * result % N;
        if ((y & oneShift63) != 0)
            result = result * x % N;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For this example: XpowYmodN(29,83,53) the result is 43. According to the manufacturer of the device calculations the result should be 50. Could anyone point me where i am doing it wrong?
I have tried with Math.pow(X,Y) % N, for this example and i get result 28. Im condused and would like some tips on how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: 43 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the class `java.math.BigInteger`? This class has a method called `modPow()` which is designed for cryptography usage.

The usage would be

```
BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(x).modPow(BigInteger.valueof(y), BigInteger.valueOf(n));
```

By the way variables a named with lower case letters (`n` in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. But the value the calculator provides is not the calculation but the exchanged key. And your answer refers to the public value as seen by the sender or receiver

Answer (score 0):

I tested various numbers into that function and it worked great. I then created a duplicate function that used the following code based on Uwe Plonus' answer:

```
public long XpowYmodN(long x, long y, long N) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(x).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(y), BigInteger.valueOf(N)).longValue();
}
```

I tested your numbers into it and got 43, just like that function; so that function seems to be working perfectly. The person that posted 29,83,53 numbers as resulting in 50 appears to be wrong. The correct answer for 29,83,53 is 43.

Here's the complete code I used:

```
public class Main {
    public static long XpowYmodN_(long x, long y, long N) {
        long result = 1;
        final long oneShift63 = ((long) 1) << 63;

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; y <<= 1, i++) {
            result = result * result % N;
            if ((y & oneShift63) != 0)
                result = result * x % N;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static long XpowYmodN(long x, long y, long N) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(x).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(y), BigInteger.valueOf(N)).longValue();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("BEGIN main");


        System.out.println(Main.XpowYmodN_(29,83,53));
        System.out.println(Main.XpowYmodN(29,83,53));
    }
}
```

which gave the output of:

```
BEGIN main
43
43
```